# Puppet install DS with 2 different commands and only if

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am not very experienced in Puppet and I really need your help.

I have 2 servers where I need to install DS (ed. *Directory Server*) . Is running without error but in the servers not run these commands. What I made wrong?

```rb
exec { 'Install first DS':
    command     => "setup  --serverId first-ds --deploymentKeyPassword ${prof_ds::constants::deployment_pwd} --deploymentKey ${prof_ds::constants::deployment_key} --rootUserDn ${prof_ds::constants::admin_user}  --rootUserPassword ${prof_ds::constants::admin_pwd} --monitorUserPassword ${prof_ds::constants::monitor_pwd} --hostname ${::fqdn} --ldapPort ${prof_ds::constants::ldap_port} --ldapsPort ${prof_ds::constants::ldaps_port} --httpsPort ${prof_ds::constants::https_port} --adminConnectorPort ${prof_ds::constants::admin_port} --replicationPort ${prof_ds::constants::replication_port}  --start  --acceptLicense",
    onlyif      => ['test "${::fqdn}" == "${ds_hosts[0]}" && echo 0 || echo 1'],
    environment => ["JAVA_HOME=${java_home}"],
    path        => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin', '/opt/opendj','/opt/opendj/bin'],
  }

exec { 'Install second DS':
    command     => "setup  --serverId second-ds --deploymentKeyPassword ${prof_ds::constants::deployment_pwd} --deploymentKey ${prof_ds::constants::deployment_key} --rootUserDn ${prof_ds::constants::admin_user} --rootUserPassword ${prof_ds::constants::admin_pwd} --monitorUserPassword ${prof_ds::constants::monitor_pwd} --hostname ${::fqdn} --ldapPort ${prof_ds::constants::ldap_port} --ldapsPort ${prof_ds::constants::ldaps_port} --httpsPort ${prof_ds::constants::https_port} --adminConnectorPort ${prof_ds::constants::admin_port} --replicationPort ${prof_ds::constants::replication_port} --bootstrapReplicationServer ${ds_hosts[0]}:${prof_ds::constants::replication_port} --start --acceptLicense",
    onlyif      => ['test "${::fqdn}" == "${ds_hosts[1]}" && echo 0 || echo 1'],
    environment => ["JAVA_HOME=${java_home}"],
    path        => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin', '/opt/opendj','/opt/opendj/bin'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume your commands are correct. So what may need to be fixed is the `onlyif` command, that means that the exec command is going to be ran `onlyif` it will return a non-zero output ([more](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.21/types/exec.html#exec)). The command will run and will [interpolate](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.21/lang_variables.html) when using double-quote and will not if used single quote (is a Ruby standard rather than Puppet)

The full code:

```rb
if $::hostname == $ds_hosts[0] {
  exec { 'setup first-ds':
    command     => "setup  --serverId first-ds --deploymentKeyPassword ${prof_ds::constants::deployment_pwd} --deploymentKey ${prof_ds::constants::deployment_key} --rootUserDn ${prof_ds::constants::admin_user}  --rootUserPassword ${prof_ds::constants::admin_pwd} --monitorUserPassword ${prof_ds::constants::monitor_pwd} --hostname ${::fqdn} --ldapPort ${prof_ds::constants::ldap_port} --ldapsPort ${prof_ds::constants::ldaps_port} --httpsPort ${prof_ds::constants::https_port} --adminConnectorPort ${prof_ds::constants::admin_port} --replicationPort ${prof_ds::constants::replication_port}  --start  --acceptLicense",
    onlyif      => ["test '${::fqdn}' == '${ds_hosts[0]}' && echo 0 || echo 1"],
    environment => ["JAVA_HOME=${java_home}"],
    path        => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin', '/opt/opendj','/opt/opendj/bin'],
  }
}

if $::hostname == $ds_hosts[1] {
  exec { 'setup second-ds':
    command     => "setup  --serverId second-ds --deploymentKeyPassword ${prof_ds::constants::deployment_pwd} --deploymentKey ${prof_ds::constants::deployment_key} --rootUserDn ${prof_ds::constants::admin_user} --rootUserPassword ${prof_ds::constants::admin_pwd} --monitorUserPassword ${prof_ds::constants::monitor_pwd} --hostname ${::fqdn} --ldapPort ${prof_ds::constants::ldap_port} --ldapsPort ${prof_ds::constants::ldaps_port} --httpsPort ${prof_ds::constants::https_port} --adminConnectorPort ${prof_ds::constants::admin_port} --replicationPort ${prof_ds::constants::replication_port} --bootstrapReplicationServer ${ds_hosts[0]}:${prof_ds::constants::replication_port} --start --acceptLicense",
    onlyif      => ["test '${::fqdn}' == '${ds_hosts[1]}' && echo 0 || echo 1"],
    environment => ["JAVA_HOME=${java_home}"],
    path        => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin', '/opt/opendj','/opt/opendj/bin'],
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
Another optimization I recommend is avoid testing empty strings (depends on the OS/version), by adding another char in front, e.g. **`x`**:

```
test 'x${::fqdn}' == 'x${ds_hosts[0]}' && echo 0 || echo 1
```

UPDATE:
More on how you can restrict exec on specific nodes ([more](https://serverfault.com/questions/581419/puppet-include-other-files-depending-on-hostname/581441)), in a very simple empirical way (updated the code snippet above, too)

However, the proper way to restrict specific execution on specific nodes, is to either have 2 Nodegroups: `Directory Service Primary` and `Directory Service Secondary`, pin each node to its counterpart, and use the [resource collector](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.5/lang_collectors.html) feature to distribute the work on different nodes.

Another note is that you should avoid using `exec` resource as they are not idempotent. If that is not possible, to define a type that would wrap that resource and manage all of its lifecycle. In your case would be something like:

```rb
directory_service { 'first-ds':
  deploymentKeyPassword => '?',
  deploymentKey => '?',
}
```

This would probably come later, when you understand how do you want to manage the configurations of your DS service. To get inspired, check [apache](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache). Looking on [forge](https://forge.puppet.com/modules?utf-8=%E2%9C%93&page_size=25&sort=rank&q=ds) for DS, one module raised my attention: [markt-de/puppet-ds_389](https://github.com/markt-de/puppet-ds_389)

Comment: I tried like this, but is not working :(. First command is running on both servers :(. I running this on Redhat. What I try to do is to run 2 different command in two servers. (server 1 command 1 and servers 2 command 2)

Comment: Add this (that each command runs on different node) detail to your question. The resource `exec` needs to distinguish between `server1`, let's call it `nodeA` and `nodeB`. This is done either by `fact` or by the `test`. How/When do you know which is `nodeA` and `nodeB`

Comment: Hello azbarcea,

node 1 is ${ds_hosts[0]} and node 2 is ${ds_hosts[1]}. I don't know how to restrict exec on each node. on node 1 first comand and on node 2 second command.

Thanks

Comment: @CristianMesaros - updated the answer above too. In that particular case, you don't need anymore: `test '${::fqdn}' == '${ds_hosts[0]}' && echo 0 || echo 1"`. Actually the `test` should be something like: `test <i don't really need to run exec>`. Puppet is meant to be idempotent, so in this case **you want to avoid running the setup every single Puppet execution**.

Comment: azbarcea sorry, but not understand how can I  do it. can you be more explicit ?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onlyif` attributes are nonsense on several levels.  Your other answer points out some of these, but for completeness:

- An `Exec`'s `onlyif` attribute should be a single command, as a string.  You may be lucking out via stringification of the arrays you are actually presenting, but you really ought to make them plain strings.
- By putting the `onlyif` command in single quotes, you prevent Puppet from interpolating values for the Puppet variable references within.
- You appear to have the idea that it is the standard output of the `onlyif` command that determines whether the main command will be run, but that is incorrect: it is the `onlyif`'s *exit status*.
- Since all the details being tested are known during catalog building, it is pointless to use an `onlyif` attribute at all.  A Puppet conditional statement would be better suited.
- But what you *should* use an `unless` or `onlyif` or `creates` for is to prevent installing the software again if it has already been installed.

Overall, then, you want something more like this:

```
  if $::fqdn == $ds_hosts[0] {
    exec { 'Install first DS':
      command     => "setup  --serverId first-ds ...",
      environment => ["JAVA_HOME=${java_home}"],
      path        => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin', '/opt/opendj','/opt/opendj/bin'],
      unless      => "exit_with_status_0_if_DS_is_already_installed",
    }
  } elsif $::fqdn == $ds_hosts[1] {
    exec { 'Install second DS':
      command     => "setup  --serverId second-ds  ...",
      environment => ["JAVA_HOME=${java_home}"],
      path        => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin', '/opt/opendj','/opt/opendj/bin'],
      unless      => "exit_with_status_0_if_DS_is_already_installed",
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @John Bollinger is working. Very good explanation, thanks a lot.